# How to remove event listener from event bubbling child

Tags: javascript, events

i have an ul list with 16 li element childs.

I create the HTML elements with js. There i add an Eventlistener(clickevent) on the ul element. -> event bubbling

Now when the element gets clicked, i want to remove the Eventlistener, so the element cannot be clicked again.

How can i remove an Eventlistener from the child li of the parent ul. But only for this now clicked child? So i can still click on the other 15 li elements?

i was trying to find a way around but i need help.

```html
<ul class="stars">
   <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
   <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
   <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
</ul>
```

i select the ul and add nen eventListener

```
´´´
ulDeck = document.querySelector(".stars");
ulDeck.addEventListener('click', showStar, false);
´´´
```

then i create the li elements

´´´

```
for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    // Create new li elm
    let li = document.createElement("li");
```

´´´

Comment: You should probably add the JavaScript in your code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
const nodeList = document.getElementsByClassName('stars')[0].getElementsByTagName('li')

for (let idx = 0; idx < nodeList.length; idx++) {
  const item = nodeList[idx]
  const itemListener = function(e) {
    console.log('CLICK!')
    item.removeEventListener('click', itemListener)  
  }
  item.addEventListener('click', itemListener)
}
```

```html
<ul class="stars">
   <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
   <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
   <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the click event handler to the *ul* children and implement some javascript like that:

```
document.querySelectorAll('ul li').forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if (e.target.classList.contains('clicked')) return;
        //your code here...
        e.target.classList.add('clicked');
    });
});
```

This snippet is preventing your code from being executed in case the clicked *ul* child already has a "*clicked*" class assigned to it.